# Pointwise and Uniform Convergence Proof

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having real problems doing this question, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Define the functions $f_n(x) : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R} \ $ by $f_n(x) = n^
px \exp(-n^qx)$ where $\ p, q > 0$.

(a) Show that $f_n → 0 \ $ pointwise on $[0, 1] \ $ as $ \ n → ∞$. [Hint: you may find
useful to use the inequality $e^y >y^k/k! \ $ $∀k ∈ N, \ ∀ y > 0$].

(b) Find $||f_n||_∞$ and deduce that if $ \ p < q \ $ then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $[0, 1]$ whereas if $ \ p ≥ q \ $ then $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly on $[0, 1]$.
Does $(f_n)$ converge uniformly on $[0, 1−ϵ]$? Does $(f_n)$ converge uniformly on $[ϵ, 1]$?

Comment: Looks to me like $f_n(x) \to \infty$ pointwise on $(0,1].$

Comment: Apologies, I left off a minus sign.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, but it would be good if you learned some basic LaTex. It would also be good if you discussed your thoughts on the problem, some context, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely will do that! I don't know how best to apply the inequality and how to go about proving pointwise continuity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove the pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ using the given inequality.

Note that we can rewrite the inequality to $\frac{1}{e^y} < k! \frac{1}{y^k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y>0$. Given that $n^q x>0$, we deduce the following for $x \in (0,1]$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$f_n(x) = n^px e^{-n^qx} = n^px\frac{1}{e^{n^qx}} < n^p x  \frac{k!}{(n^q x)^k} = k! \;n^{p-kq} x^{1-k}$$
Choose a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $qk>p$, and thus $p-qk<0$. In that case $n^{p-qk}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Note that $f_n$ is positive for every $n$. We find $\forall x \in (0,1]$:
$$0 \leq f_n(x) <k! \;n^{p-kq} x^{1-k} \to 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad f_n(x) \to 0$$
Considering that $f_n(0)=0$ for every $n$, we conclude that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise. $\Box$

To find $\|f_n\|_\infty$ you should calculate the maximum value of $f_n$ on $[0,1]$.